# Django: "NOT NULL constraint failed: users_investment.user_id" Error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a project where I would like for many users to register for many offered_funds, so I added a ManyToManyField. I also wanted Django to automatically figure out which user was logged in and auto fill the user field so I wrote it in my views.py file. However upon doing so, I came across the error:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: users_investment.user_id

Here is my models.py:

```
# Not sure if this class is relevant to my question
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=55, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Investment(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    offered_fund = models.ForeignKey(OfferedFunds)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.offered_fund.fund_name.name
```

my forms.py:

```
class InvestmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ('offered_fund','amount')
        exclude = ['user']
```

and finally, my views.py:

```
def of_details(request, slug):
    context_dict = {}

    of = get_object_or_404(OfferedFunds, slug=slug)
    context_dict['of'] = of

    default_state = OfferedFunds.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = InvestmentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'offered_fund': default_state})

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        #instance.user = request.user
        instance.offered_fund = default_state
        instance.save()
        instance.user.add(request.user) # Where the problem started
    context_dict['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'funds/offered-funds-details.html', context_dict)
```

In my views.py I have commented the bit of code that lead to this issue.I cant imagine why Django would be mad that the user field has a value (not null). Anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this? I've don't a python manage.py flush to clear my database already, and still no luck. Thanks

Comment: Is the user logged in? Check what user instance in `request.user`.

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in, I did a `print("request.user")` to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are receiving an [anonymous user object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users) instead of a fully authenticated user (Django will automatically populate `request.user` with an anonymous user if an authenticated user isn't logged in. The `id` for an anonymous user is always `None` - hence the database constraint fails.

You need to make sure that your user isn't anonymous by checking whether `request.user.is_authenticated()` first:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    instance.user.add(request.user)
```

Comment: No I'm logged in, and I still get the error, I even tried `print("request.user")` just to make sure.

Comment: What is the contents of `request.user`?

Comment: `request.user` returns the name of the logged in user (I am logged in as the superuser you create when you run `syncdb`). I also have a UsersProfile class in my models.py. I've edited my original post to reflect that.

Comment: So, I am pretty sure that your problem is missing or failed migrations. Please try `manage.py makemigrations` followed by `manage.py migrate`.